# text in a <span> breaks into two lines in WebView on android kitkat only

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="news_detail">
    <span class="newspaper_icon"></span>
    <span class="small_story_newspaper">Sky News</span>
</div>
```

and the following CSS applied:

```
.news_detail {
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.newspaper_icon {
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    background: url("images/Mobile/hdpi.png") no-repeat scroll 0px -342px / 215px auto transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
.small_story_newspaper {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(41, 169, 224);
}
```

It works perfect on all but android devices with Kitkat.
Any ideas?
I know that on Kitkat the `WebView` is using chromium now. Does chromium has issues with `<span>` that I need to know?

Comment: Can you give a demo of this on jsbin.com and if possible some screenshots of it happening? Does Chrome for Android do the same thing? Judging by your CSS, this could easily wrap and be valid for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that inline-block is not supported on mentioned device. Try display block with float. Also kitkat is only running on 1% of android devices, so I wouldnt bother

Comment: -1: Kitkat is running on 1% of devices NOW but that number is only going to increase. If it was a bug on Froyo, then you possibly could ignore it. You SHOULD fix it, and before Kitkat becomes popular.